# Woocommerce new order then save

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I need to create a function that looks for all the new orders entered in woocommerce and then just update this order without changing anything. (like if you clicked on the order and then clicked update with everything remaining the same)

The reason for this is that I'm bringing orders from another source into woocommerce but the plugin to export them to another platform isn't listening for these external orders until they are updated even if nothing changes.

I know I have to use the woocommerce_new_order hook to listen for the new orders coming in but how can I just update it without changing anything?

```
function custom_woocommerce_order($order_id) {
if (!$order_id) {
    return;
}
//Will this work for what I need?
$order_id = $order->save();
//Or should I do this instead?
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
do_action( 'woocommerce_update_order', $order ); 
}

add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'custom_woocommerce_order');
```

Comment: This is not a great fit for questions for StackOverflow. This is more of a "I need some code written" rather than a question with a single definitive answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @Danack I could get some orientation into what hook I can use to update the order. Looks like you have a lot of time to not be helpful at all?